# trigger to maintain total

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have created some tables for invoicing.

There is a invoice_header and invoice_detail table. The invoice details contains in the invoice detail lines, invoice_header_id, qty, unit_price, tax_amount etc

The invoice header has the billing address, invoice no, invoice_total, etc

I have created a trigger for insert/update/delete so that the invoice_total in the header is the sum(invoice_details.qty * invoice_details.unit_price)

There is one case I am not sure how to cater for.
If I update an invoice_detail line, to associate it with a different header. 
like this

```
UPDATE invoice_details SET invoice_header_id=1 WHERE invoice_header_id=2
```

The trigger will fire but it will update the old header record total but not the new one. How can I cater for that circumstance?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but what does your trigger create look like? Maybe you need `AFTER` insert/update instead of `BEFORE`?

Comment: Just an idea: I would create a view on your details that calculates the header on the fly. That way it's alway correct. You are denormalizing data, which usually leads to hassles like this. Only if performance is a real problem should you consider your design.

Comment: @Bohemian, I didn't really think about views as an option, I might give that a go. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you?

From [Mysql trigger syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.
>
> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
>   row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no
>   new row. In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of the row after it is updated.
>
> A column named with OLD is read only. You can refer to it (if you have
>   the SELECT privilege), but not modify it. You can refer to a column
>   named with NEW if you have the SELECT privilege for it. In a BEFORE
>   trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value
>   if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a
>   trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to
>   update a row. (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger
>   because the row change will have already occurred.)

So, you would have OLD.invoice_header_id (2) and NEW.invoice_header_id (1) Inside the trigger for you to update invoice_header

```
CREATE TRIGGER check BEFORE UPDATE ON invoice_detail
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.invoice_header_id <> OLD.invoice_header_id THEN
        You Do the math and update both invoice_header lines
    END IF;
END
```